# clang++ unable to recognize 'nullptr' without flag

Tags: c++, clang++, apple-clang

I am running:

```
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

when I run: `clang++ *.cpp -o test`, I get:

```
    identifier = nullptr;
                  ^
1 error generated.
```

however, when I run: `clang++ -std=c++11 *.cpp -o test`, I get no errors.

Does anyone else have this issue with the latest version of clang?

Whoever set the duplicate flag, this is not a duplicate. I had made the reasonable assumption that the latest version of clang wouldn't be running C++98 by default. Also, the linked post is from 10 years ago, when C++11 got released...

Comment: For whatever reason the Apple version of clang defaults to a very old standard so you need to specify the newer standard yourself.

Comment: nullptr _is_ a c++11 feature.

Comment: 14 is not latest :P  ANd that's expected behaviour on MacOS, default standard is still gnu++98, but many build tools alias  clang usage, so some people are unaware.

Comment: You should always specify a language standard when compiling, which these days should be `‑std=c++17` at the _minimum_.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie what's the latest then?

Comment: @user18348324 It is the latest Apple clang, but upstream clang 15 has been released already in September.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple clang++ 14.0.0 defaults to C++98.

For example with this source file:

```cpp
long version = __cplusplus;
void *p = nullptr;
```

You can see this behavior:

```bash
$ clang++ -E nullptr.cpp | grep -v '^#'
long version = 199711L;
void *p = nullptr;

$ clang++ -c nullptr.cpp           
nullptr.cpp:2:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr'
void *p = nullptr;
          ^
1 error generated.

$ clang++ -c -std=c++11 nullptr.cpp
```

The solution is to explicitly request a language standard of C++11 or newer via `-std=c++XY`, as shown above.